# SVN authorization failed

Tags: windows, svn, authentication

I installed SVN in Windows XP. I got the error when I create a project. How do I fix it?

> C:\svn\bin>svn mkdir
>   svn://localhost/myproject -m "some
>   msg" --username user1 --password pass
>   svn: Authorization failed

Here is the configuration file in SVN:

### svnserve.conf

anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd

### passwd

[users]
user1=pass1
user2=pass2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the

```
authz-db = authz
```

line is uncommented, you have to modify the authz file like this:

```
[/]
me = rw
otheruser = r
```

I missed the `[/]` before and I've got the "svn: Authorization failed" on client side. But it works well now.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've got your password wrong:

C:\svn\bin>svn mkdir svn://localhost/myproject -m "some msg" --username user1 --password **pass** svn

[users]
user1=**pass1**
user2=pass2

You've entered "**pass**" but your password is specified as "**pass1**"

Comment: still no luck 

C:\svn\bin>svn mkdir svn://localhost/myproject -m "some msg" --username user1 --password pass1
svn: Authorization failed

Comment: @cc96al: Sorry then, I don't have any other ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have set up your SVN repository correctly?

Check the following

Open the file

```
<path to repository>myproject\conf\svnserve.conf
```

Check the following line aren't commented out (if the line starts with a # remove it)

```
anon-access = read  
auth-access = write  
password-db = passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should write

```
C:\svn\bin>svn mkdir svn://localhost/myproject -m "some msg" --username user1 --password pass1 svn:
```

instead, your password seems to be wrong.